# 'cacheDuration' => false, sets cache file expiration date to 1 year

Tags: cache

So I noticed that by setting the `'cacheDuration' => false` it seems to set, by default, the expiration date to 1 year from when the cache is saved.

I found this in `/app/services/TemplateCacheService.php` starting from line 263:

```
if($duration <= 0) 
{
  $duration = 31536000; // 1 year
}
```

I know a longer duration could be achieved by setting the expiration to something like `4Y`. But I wanted to raise this and ask if it was an oversight or what the reason was for setting it to a year and overriding the specific value of not setting an expiration at all...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it's slightly awkward.

First off it should be `'0'`, instead of `false` if you want it to cache indefinitely (documentation bug, just fixed).

It's slightly awkward because the `cacheDuration` config setting is used for multiple things, but when the `TemplateCacheService` uses it, it requires an expiration date (not optional).

So if it sees `0`, it will just pick one reasonably far out (a year), but you can set it to something higher if you want.

What should probably happen is everywhere that uses the `cacheDuration` config setting should have its own, separate config setting.

Not going to happen for Craft 2, but make a note to look at it once Craft 3 launches.